# Http image is not showing in TweetComposer.Builder

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using fabric to compose image and text tweets.

**Logcat:**

E/TwitterImage: https://458fbec5cf61223e14d9-6f3259da71af87ee4df772aff14bfdf0.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/temp_photo.jpg

**UsersPostAdapter.java:**

```
    Log.e("TwitterImage", ""+strShareImageUrl);

    Uri uri =  Uri.parse(strShareImageUrl);

    TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(context)
            .text(strShareText)
            .image(uri);
    builder.show();
```

I could get the text in twitter window while sharing.But images could not be display in twitter window.

I am getting toast as a `image could not be located` in twitter window.Only text is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The image Uri should be a file Uri (i.e. file://absolute_path scheme) to a local file.

Using Fresco u can do like this

```
final DataSource<CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer>> dataSource =
               ImagePipelineFactory.getInstance().getImagePipeline().fetchEncodedImage(ImageRequest.fromUri(Constants.DEFAULT_LOGO), this);

    DataSubscriber<CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer>> dataSubscriber =
            new BaseDataSubscriber<CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer>>() {
                @Override
                protected void onNewResultImpl(
                        DataSource<CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer>> dataSource) {
                    if (!dataSource.isFinished()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer> imageReference = dataSource.getResult();
                    if (imageReference != null) {
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                        PooledByteBufferInputStream pooledByteBufferInputStream;
                        try {
                            pooledByteBufferInputStream = new PooledByteBufferInputStream(imageReference.get());
                            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
                            File tempFile = AndroidUtils.createImageFile();

                            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

                            int read = 0;
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                            while ((read = pooledByteBufferInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                                fileOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                            }

                            startTwitterIntent(tempFile);

                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            AnalyticsManager.logError(e);
                            finish();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            CloseableReference.closeSafely(imageReference);
                            imageReference = null;
                            dataSource.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onFailureImpl
                        (DataSource<CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer>> dataSource) {
                    Throwable t = dataSource.getFailureCause();
                    AnalyticsManager.logError(t);
                }
            };

    dataSource.subscribe(dataSubscriber, UiThreadImmediateExecutorService.getInstance());
```

Hope it helps